# Proof about fibonacci numbers by induction

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $u_1,u_2,....$ be the fibonacci sequence.

a) Prove by induction or otherwise thar for n>0,

$$u_{n-1}+u_{n-3}+u_{n-5}+...<u_n$$

the sum on the left continuing so long as the subscript remains larger than 1

b) Show that every positive integer can be represented in a unique way in the form $u_{n_1}+u_{n_2}+....+u_{n_k}$, where $k \geq 1$, $n_{j-1} \geq n_j+2$ for $j=2,3,.....,k$ and $n_k>1$

Approach a)

Base case n=3
$u_2<u_3$

Inductive step

1) if n is even, the series terminates in $a_3$
2) if n is odd , the series terminates in $a_2$

Case 1
 Assume $u_{n-1}+u_{n-3}+u_{n-5}+...+a_3<u_n$
 Need to show $u_{n+1}+u_{n-1}+u_{n-3}+u_{n-5}...+a_3<u_{n+2}$

$$u_{n-1}+u_{n-3}+u_{n-5}+...+a_3<u_n$$
$$u_{n+1}+u_{n-1}+u_{n-3}+u_{n-5}+...+a_3<u_n+u_{n+1}$$
$$u_{n+1}+u_{n-1}+u_{n-3}+u_{n-5}+...+a_3<u_{n+2} \text{ by the fibonacci identity}$$

Similarly for case 2

Approach b)
I am still thinking about that one. The subscripts seem very confusing to me. Can anyone give me a general idea of the problem?

Approach wikipedia

The first part of Zeckendorf's theorem (existence) can be proven by induction. For n = 1, 2, 3 it is clearly true (as these are Fibonacci numbers), for $n = 4$ we have $4 = 3 + 1$. Now suppose each $n ≤ k$ has a Zeckendorf representation. If $k + 1$ is a Fibonacci number then we're done, else there exists j such that $F_j < k + 1 < F_j + 1$ . Now consider $a = k + 1 − F_j$ . Since a ≤ k, a has a Zeckendorf representation (by the induction hypothesis). At the same time, $F_j + a < F_j + 1$ and since $F_j + 1 = F_j + F_{j − 1}$ (by definition of Fibonacci numbers), a < F_{j − 1}, so the Zeckendorf representation of a does not contain F_{j − 1} . As a result, k + 1 can be represented as the sum of F_j and the Zeckendorf representation of a.

This seems clear to me up to the point where it's stated "As a result, k + 1 can be represented as the sum of F_j and the Zeckendorf representation of a." How do we know that the representations do not overlap at some number?

Comment: For the part b) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem

Comment: Your approach to part a) looks good. It might have been better to make two separate questions. That way we could give the questions more searchable titles (among other things).

Comment: so the subscripts means the following "sum does not include any two consecutive Fibonacci numbers. ". It looks like a proof from another world.

Comment: I added the proof from wikipedia and asked questions about it.