# Every positive integer $n$ has a unique representation as sum of non-consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, fibonacci-numbers

> Let $k\gg m$ mean that $k\ge m+2$. Show that every positive integer $n$
>   has a unique representation of the form
>   $$n=F_{k_1}+F_{k_2}+ \dots +F_{k_r},$$ where $F_i$ is the $i$th Fibonacci
>   number and $k_1\gg k_2\gg \dots \gg k_r \gg 0$.

Well I proved the existence part using induction on $n$. I am not getting anywhere in proving the uniqueness part. Any hints or solutions, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show that $F_n$ is greater than any number you can express with an expression of your form using only $F_m$  with $m < n$.
That is 
$$F_n>F_{k_1}+F_{k_2}+ \dots +F_{k_r},$$ where  $n-1\ge k_1\gg k_2\gg \dots \gg k_r \gg 0$.

Then assume two distinct expressions for some number exist. Let $F_n$ be the  largest number that occurs in the one, yet not in the other.

But by the observation at the start, we can never compensate this difference.

Comment: I am sorry but I dont understand your first statement.

Comment: I added some details.

Comment: Some more information is on this recent question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834225/proof-about-fibonacci-numbers-by-induction you can also search for Zeckendorf expansion.